# Brace initialization of a member array with another constexpr array

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr, list-initialization

Let's consider following illustrative example code:

```
using matrix_t = double[2][2];

constexpr matrix_t zero_matrix = {
    {0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 0.0}
};

constexpr matrix_t identity_matrix = {
    {1.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 1.0}
};

struct wrapped_matrix_t
{
    matrix_t matrix;
};

constexpr wrapped_matrix_t zero_wrapped_matrix = {
    //zero_matrix
    {
        {zero_matrix[0][0], zero_matrix[0][1]},
        {zero_matrix[1][0], zero_matrix[1][1]}
    }
};

constexpr wrapped_matrix_t identity_wrapped_matrix = {
    //identity_matrix
    {
        {identity_matrix[0][0], identity_matrix[0][1]},
        {identity_matrix[1][0], identity_matrix[1][1]}
    }
};
```

Now I would like to be able to use by `constexpr` arrays `zero_matrix` and `identity_matrix` to initialize `matrix_t` members in other types. However that seems to not be possible. Or at least simple use of the name doesn't work.

The best what I come out with is reuse of values be referring to indexes. But this is far from perfect.

Is there any way to use `zero_matrix` and `identity_matrix` directly in such initializations?

(I'm checking on GCC 6.3.0 with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11`.)

Comment: So you want to write `constexpr wrapped_matrix_t zero_wrapped_matrix{zero_matrix};` but it doesn't compile?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't compile. Regardless if I write it `zero_wrapped_matrix{zero_matrix}` or `zero_wrapped_matrix =
 {zero_matrix}`. In both cases I'm getting "_error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use `std::array` and don't have access to the implementation of `wrapped_matrix_t`, you can use *metaprogramming* to generate the indexing of the source array when initializing your wrappers. The final code will look like this:

```
constexpr wrapped_matrix_t zero_wrapped_matrix = from_array(zero_matrix);
constexpr wrapped_matrix_t identity_wrapped_matrix = from_array(identity_matrix);
```

---

I'm assuming that `matrix_t` is `double[2 * 2]`, but the technique below can be generalized to `N`-dimension arrays.

Here are the implementation details:

```
template <typename Array, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto from_array_impl(const Array& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return wrapped_matrix_t{arr[Is]...};
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto from_array(const double(&arr)[N])
{
    return from_array_impl(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

I'm basically matching the size of the array with a reference, and building a `0..N` index sequence from it. I'm then creating a `wrapped_matrix_t` by indexing the array with the sequence.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jynLArRy2j5sBnUq)

---

Here's a possible implementation for 2D arrays:

```
template <std::size_t W, typename Array, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto from_array_impl(const Array& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return wrapped_matrix_t{(arr[Is % W][Is / W])...};
}

template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
constexpr auto from_array(const double(&arr)[W][H])
{
    return from_array_impl<W>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<W * H>());
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/thM5prkn8RXR2Xgi)

Comment: My case contains also many other members in the `wrapped_matrix_t`. And they are set to different values in different `constexpr` variables. But I think it would be doable by extending the `from_array` to take those arguments as well (and probably rename it). Still this is not as nice as it would be to just use `zero_matrix` but I'm guessing this might be the only way. I will accept the answer after giving some more time.

Comment: @AdamBadura: you should really mention all of this extra constraints in the question, otherwise you will never get an answer that's valid for your real use case.

Comment: Well, that is always a trade-off between simplicity of the example and closeness to real case. In initial version I had `wrapped_matrix_t` with an extra member but in the end I removed it to shorter and cleaner example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::array` and change your representation to an 1D array.

```
using matrix_t = std::array<double, 2 * 2>;

constexpr matrix_t zero_matrix = {
    {0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0}
};

constexpr matrix_t identity_matrix = {
    {1.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 1.0}
};

struct wrapped_matrix_t
{
    matrix_t matrix;
};

constexpr wrapped_matrix_t zero_wrapped_matrix{zero_matrix};
constexpr wrapped_matrix_t identity_wrapped_matrix{zero_matrix};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TBipkI7vXorLDm4Z)

---

In order to access the 1D array as if it was a 2D one, you can use the following formula: `(x, y) => x + y * width`.

It is possible to create a wrapper around `std::array` that provides a 2D-like interface, if you so desire.

Comment: In my real case I already have 1D array so one problem less! However, the `wrapped_matrix_t` is in my case a C POD out of my control so I cannot use `std::array`. Also - to be honest - this is still far from perfect solution...

Comment: @AdamBadura: added another answer with a different approach.